# How to make pagination with unclear values?

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I have a list of rooms (users) to chat which I get via socket.io.

And I want to paginate this list using **ngb-pagination**.

But in response I get a bunch of errors:

How to fix it?

> Parser Error: Cannot have a pipe in an action expression at column 11
> in [(rooms$ | async)?.meta?.currentPage=$event]

**html:**

```
<ngb-pagination [collectionSize]="(rooms$ | async)?.meta?.totalItems" [(page)]="(rooms$ | async)?.meta?.currentPage"
    [pageSize]="(rooms$ | async)?.meta?.itemsPerPage" (pageChange)="onPaginateRooms($event)">
</ngb-pagination>
```

**ts:**

```
export declare class PageEvent {
  pageIndex: number;
  previousPageIndex?: number;
  pageSize: number;
  length: number;
}

rooms$: Observable<RoomPaginateI> = this.chatService.getMyRooms();

ngOnInit() {
  this.chatService.emitPaginateRooms(10, 0);
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.chatService.emitPaginateRooms(10, 0);
}

onPaginateRooms(pageEvent: PageEvent) {
  this.chatService.emitPaginateRooms(pageEvent.pageSize, pageEvent.pageIndex);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Action expressions can't contain the `async` pipe.

```
[(page)]="(rooms$ | async)?.meta?.currentPage" // <--- Erorr
```

So you can modify it to be `[page]="(rooms$ | async)?.meta?.currentPage"`, and you are already passing the event to `onPaginateRooms($event)`, so you can update your `currentPage` with the emitted page value from `(pageChange)`